# How to inset a face?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to set up a Minecraft rig mouth that will have more controls and will be rounded, but I am having issues trying to figure out what this guy did here. First, he did what looked like a loop cut and slide, but instead of drawing a line it selected all the edges it passed through. He then cut to a new clip where the mouth was already set up like this.

[image]

The video is in 3 times speed but if you download a youtube plugin you can slow it down to 0.25 speed of the video and then if you do the spacebar trick you can slow it down so it shows 1 frame at a time and it is really slow. [Here is the link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YXAEld0t0w&list=SPKVTzPxdshlFigjKjJfrUiTpQ9-r_hg_t&index=7) if you want or need to see the video.

All I am asking is how can I create those 8 basic segments.

Comment: You do know that the linked video is not of blender, right?

Comment: Yeah and neither is picture but it is same concept. I have used some of this video to make other features. You can do most of the stuff in Maya in Blender, Cinema 4D, and 3DS Max. gandalf3 all I am asking is how can I draw those 6 basic segments.

Comment: Which segments? Just be aware that other softwares will have different tools and different workflows.

Comment: First I did my math wrong it is 8 segments my bad. LOL :) But the 4 diagonals and the rectangle in the middle.

Comment: You could use *Inset* (`I`)

Comment: Oh my god that might actually work thanks let me try it.

Comment: I edited your question to better reflect your comments, please [rollback](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) my edits if they are incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [*Inset*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?#inset-faces) tool (<kbd>`I`</kbd>):

> This tool takes the currently selected faces and creates an inset of
>   them, with adjustable thickness and depth. The tool is modal, such
>   that when you activate it, you may adjust the thickness with your
>   mouse position. You may also adjust the depth of the inset during the
>   modal operation by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

1. Select the faces to inset:

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>`I`</kbd> to inset:

   [image]

Comment: This worked great although the picture and video were of Maya, the answer was found. I feel stupid but thank you so much!

Comment: @GarrettLozano All I meant is that the tools for insetting in Maya _may_ be different from the tools in blender.

Comment: Oh alright well I apologize for misunderstanding but no they don't seem to be because I got the same result and thank you so much it helped a ton.

Comment: @GarrettLozano Np. Glad it helped :)