# Thick extrude along edges

Tags: extrude

I'm fairly new to Blender.  I am trying to inset the roof on the top of this building...the roof is below the top of the walls. As you can see from the picture, the wall is higher than the roof with a thick border along the edge. What I need is a kind of "create inner edge (or cut) along the border" at the same distance from my existing border all the way around so I can keep the wall height and lower the plane of the roof down where it should be. Can someone tell me how to do this?

[image: Top view of building]

Comment: Try to use the inset tool. "I" key to inset. During the operation, look at the options in the bottom bar. Whilst done, you can set the exact wanted distance in the operator panel.

Comment: Wish I could upvote your answer.  I obviously have some learning to do.  Thanks.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4834/how-to-inset-a-face or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66246/how-to-offset-the-edges